# db + php counter stock at value of 10

Tags: counter

Good day to everybody

I have a simple counter php+db
it checks ref number of the last content that was added and gives a ref number to newly added content by adding + 1 to the previous ref number of specific content type (order).
it works fine till it gets to ref number 10, then it stock and gives only 10 to content that i add.
so i cant add content with ref number 11 and 12, 13 ,14 ...
drupal 7 
thank you for your time and help.

```
if (empty($node->title)){
drupal_set_message('new node');

$query = db_select('node', 'n');
$query->condition('n.type', 'order', '=');
$query->fields('n', array('title'));
$query->orderby('title','DESC');
$query->range(0, 1);
$query->execute();
$result = $query->execute();

$record = $result->fetchAssoc();
drupal_set_message('previous order №: ' .print_r($record['title'], true));
$title = $record['title'] + 1;
drupal_set_message('order №: ' .print_r($title, true));
$form_state['node']->title = $title;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are tring to re-implement the `auto-increment` feature...

Comment: There is not enough information in the question to answer... Please add more details, especially the table layout. This smells of a column type of a single character...

Comment: you are right. its getting stock at 10. so i cant get ref  number hire then 10.

Comment: 'This smells of a column type of a single character' how to check it?

Comment: As said: post the table definition! For example run a `DESCRIBE <tablename>` in a mysql console to get it...

Comment: varchar(255)  utf8_general_ci  
The title of this node, always treated as non-markup plain text

Comment: Don't know much about drupal, so I don't know the database abstraction layer used here. So: what does `range(0,1)` do exactly?

Comment: $query->orderby('title','DESC');
    $query->range(0, 1);

it should pick up the max value/last added content.

Comment: max value of fild title (prev ref number)

Comment: Wait a minute: you use a varchar column to store a numerical index? Though you can do that I ask myself: an alphabetical sorting will obviously always have the 9 as last, regarless of any numbers higher that 9 are stored. To verify run the query manually in a sql console. You will see that 9 comes _before_ 10 or 11 or 102856394 when sorting that way. You have to use a numerical column type to get the expected result. Or you have to use a much more complex sorting strategy.

Comment: I think you are right... let me check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after a lengthy discussion the answer is:

You cannot use an alphanumerical column type (varchar(255)) and expect an alphanumerical descending sorting to produce the highest *number* stored inside that column. This is because a leading '9' will always come out *before* anything else, even if values like 10, 11, 3529 or whatever iares stored inside that column.

You either have to change the column type to a numerical type or use a much more complex sorting strategy. If you cannot change the type of that column then you might want to have a try using type casting in your SELECT query and sort by the *result* of that type cast. Though such approach is very slow and inefficient.

Also note that your algorithm is unsafe, another insert query might interfere whilst you are still computing your next index if you are working without transactions.

Comment: Arkascha, you was right. thank you for your answer.  I've tried to change the column type to a numerical type but it would kill my db.   So the only option for me is to apply 'complex sorting strategy'. 
I try to go with:
    $query->addExpression('CAST(title AS INTEGER)', 'value');
but no luck.
help is needed.  thanks

Comment: Um, what do you mean by 'it killed my db'? Certainly you can convert a table columns type. So what is the problem? Don't go fo the complex approach just because the easy solution does not work on first try!

Comment: I put ref number to title field and if i convert columns it will influence all other nodes/contents that are already in db, unless there is a way to convert columns only for one type of content.  
or i can create one more field for this type of content convert it and put there ref number... I need advice. what would be the right way of doing it?

Comment: Ah, that table is also used for other titles, probably alphanumerical names. Then obviously you cannot convert its type. I'd say the easiest solution would be to stick with the numerical titles (maxbe add a fixed prefix), but to create a fixed length numerical string instead of a plain number. For example something like `something-000000473` for the 473th entry of that type. That name scheme will give you the expected sorting order because of the leading zeros. Just make sure you have no conflicts with the other titles, this is why I suggest a fixed prefix.